# Finding child Documents from parent modal - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have User Schema and View Schema such that each user have multiple view documents
Here is my views schema

```
  var ViewsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
       userId: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User',
       },
    })
```

Now I am fetching all users and i want to fetch each user view as well in one query. I tried to use virtual property in User schema something like this

```
  UserSchema.virtual('views').get(function () {
          return Views.find({ userId: this._id });
    });
```

But it does not create any property for views in each user document.
I also tried this way

```
 UserSchema.virtual('views', {
         ref: 'Views',
         foreignField: 'userId',
         localField: '_id',
    });
   let doc = await User.find({}).populate('views');
```

But this also does not works. Anyone can tell me what are best possible ways to find Each user view in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your schema references around. In your `User` schema create a reference to the `View` schema like so ensuring that you define an array of `viewIds`:

```js
 const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
       viewIds: [{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'View'
       }]
    })
```

Now when you use your `User` model to find the documents just `populate` the references like so:

```js
 const doc =  await User.find({}).populate({ path: 'viewIds'});
```

Read about how the populate method works [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).